# Given an array of probabilities, can AnyDice output the number of specific die type (d6) combinations to best fit?

Tags: statistics, anydice

Given an array of *probabilities*:

```
 5%  5%  4%  2%  1%
12% 12% 10%  6%  4%
42% 41% 38% 23% 11%
53% 51% 45% 21%  9%
87% 86% 80% 54% 31%
```

Can AnyDice generate a list combinations using only Nd6 ± Y that would fit? Thanks in advance, [this article](https://anydice.com/articles/rolling-within-a-range/) got me started in the right direction but I'm stuck now.

The link I posted provides probability tables and charts based on a range of possible dice used to generate probabilities. What I'm looking for is the reverse: is it possible to instruct AnyDice with a range of probabilities and then have it produce die combinations, using only d6, that would fit the entire range? I'd expect output such as: 3d6+2, 10d6, 5d6+4, 2d6+12, etc.

Comment: Welcome to the Stack! There's a few things in your post that are confusing to me. You refer to the numbers you provided as an array of "probabilities", but they're integer values. Are they meant to be weights, or outcomes, or percentages? Additionally, the question is asking for a list of combinations using only Nd6±Y, but it's not clear what that result would look like. Could you provide a simpler example of what kind of output you're looking for/expecting so we can better understand what you're trying to solve?

Comment: Thanks. These are percentages.
I was looking for output like a range of dice combinations: 5d6+4, 3d6+8, 10d6, etc.

Comment: Could you edit in a more comprehensive breakdown of what you're trying to do, and what kind of output you're expecting to get? I don't think we have enough information to provide assistance in the current state of the question.

Comment: What I don't understand in your question is the table. By definition of probability, the sum of all outcomes must give 100%. If we add your numbers either rowwise or columnwise, we always find more than 100%. What exactly does the table mean?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: This still seems unclear to me, for basically the reason @ZwiQ described. Even after reading the linked page, I still can't make any sense of how your table is supposed to describe the results of a single dice roll (or, if it's supposed to describe _multiple_ rolls, how to split it up). Please describe what the probabilities in your table are supposed to be probabilities _of_.

Comment: Anyway, I could just completely ignore the (meaningless?) table and answer the rest of your question, but I'm not sure if that answer would help you. The results wouldn't look anything like your table in any sense or form, so if the table _does_ somehow relate to what you want, my answer would likely be useless to you.

Comment: This question is also unclear to me.  Dice provide numbers, not probabilities.  In order to get dice to "fit" the probabilities you provided, we'll need more information.